# Hit Internal network rest service from external server client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-services, rest

I am trying to write client side code to hit a rest service on another internal server that contains no public ip address. Because of this I am trying to write a small web service to take the id it needs and hit the rest service from the web server.

I have created a web service as shown below to hit the rest service from the web server and while I have success, the client side

```
<System.Web.Services.Webmethod()> _
        Public Shared Function GetService(ByVal id as Integer) as String
            dim serviceUrl as string = "http://192.168.0.87/rest/services/"
            dim httpWebRequest as System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl)
              httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json"
              httpWebRequest.Method = "GET"


              dim httpResponse as System.Net.HttpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse()
              Using streamReader as new System.IO.StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())

                Return streamReader.ReadToEnd()        
             End Using
        End Function
```

While this works correctly for one call, that same call's results then references URL's for further service calls e.g fetching images etc.

Is there any .Net applications out there, or any solutions out there to write a service with the external ip address and a specific path and automatically redirect the address server side into the internal ip address's rest call.

e.g if a client hit `203.141.86.2/rest/services` it would automatically translate into the internal ip address of `192.168.082/rest/services` via a middle man service.

e.g the 203.141.86.2/rest/services would actually be a real address that would just translate everything after it and put it into the new address.
Note: The existing solution is written in web forms and not in MVC, so I am unsure if a new single IIS application needs to be set up to handle these call translations as a webapi.

It is basically being like NAT service.

Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a relatively complex topic, and far too big for a stack overflow answer.  However, you may find the following article useful.  It's designed for Azure, but since you're trying to connect to a restful service in the same way, it will likely work for you, it uses WCF Routing services.  http://blog.kloud.com.au/2012/11/09/build-a-restful-router-using-wcf-browse-azure-table-storage-with-excel/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called reverse-proxy.  Try nginx. http://nginx.org

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a native application rather than using a reverse proxy?

Comment: NGINX is very native, and extremely efficient. From your question: "... would just translate everything after it and put it into the new address ..." that is exactly what it can do.

Comment: My issue is my existing clients would have to pass this request for a reverse proxy to their IT teams, which could take months to be approved from history. I would prefer to be able to write a quick redirect service regardless of how inefficient it is and handle it myself than giving the IT teams work.

Comment: Check out existing reverse-proxy code.  i.e. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31329/Simple-Reverse-Proxy-in-C-description-and-depl